# R Language Probability Estimation - Results Are All Zero?

Tags: r, probability

The R snipped below, taken from my [17-Week Coin Flip question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373944/17-week-coin-flip-contest-calculate-probability-odds-for-each-individual-to-ha) on the Cross Validated Stack Exchange, contains two sections: the first, to estimate probability of contest participants winning the contest based on their current scores and the number of weeks left in the contest; the second, to validate the estimate with a simulation.

The simulation section produces results every time, which according to the original question/answer does validate the estimate. However, every time I run this code snippet with [an online R compiler](https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler), the estimate section produces nothing but zeroes.

I've tried as best I can to debug the code, but I don't know enough about R to fix it. Would ye merry souls of Stack Overflow kindly take a look and give me shove in the right direction?

```
#
# Inputs.
#
x <- c(0,2,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,20) # Current scores
n <- 17 - 7            # Number of rounds left
n.flips <- 3           # Flips per round
p <- 1/2               # Chance of success per flip

#
# Derived quantities.
#
n.players <- length(x)        # Number of players
m <- n.flips * n              # Number of flips to go
z <- 0:m                      # Possible outcomes for any player
prob <- dbinom(z, n.flips, p) # Their chances

#
# Compute individual chances of wins and ties. 
# 
scores <- sort(unique(x))
chances <- sapply(scores, function(score)
{
  j <- min(which(x == score))

  y1 <- sapply(0:m, function(k)
  {
    exp(sum(pbinom(x[j] + k - x[(1:n.players)[-j]], m, p, log.p=TRUE)))
  })

  y <- sapply(0:n.flips, function(k)
  {
    exp(sum(pbinom(x[j] + k-1 - x[(1:n.players)[-j]], m, p, log.p=TRUE)))
  })

  c(Win=sum(prob * y), Tie=sum(prob * (y1-y)))
})

#
# Check with a simulation.  It will do a few thousand iterations per second.
#
set.seed(17)
sim <- replicate(1e4,
{
  Z <- rbinom(n.players, m, p) # The future results
  final <- x + Z               # The final scores
  scores <- table(final)       # The unique final scores
  k <- length(scores)

  if (scores[k]==1)
  {
    Win <- final == max(final) # Tally who wins
    Tie <- rep(0, n.players)
  }
  else
  {
    Tie <- final == max(final) # Tally who ties
    Win <- rep(0, n.players)
  }

  rbind(Win, Tie)
})

sim <- apply(sim, 1:2, mean)   # Average over the iterations

#
# Display the results.
#
colnames(chances) <- paste(scores)
scores <- sort(unique(x))

sim <- sapply(scores, function(score) sim[, min(which(x==score))])
colnames(sim) <- paste(sort(unique(x)))

print(round(chances, 4))
print(round(sim, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but some problems I saw.

In this line -

`z <- 0:m # Possible outcomes for any player`

you get the vector-

> [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

but each player flips the coin only 3 times, so the possible outcomes are only `0 1 2 3` as a result, your prob vector looks like this-

> [1] 0.125 0.375 0.375 0.125 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
>    0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000

(because only the 4 first outcomes are relevant)

I don't have the time now to go over the rest of your code, maybe later. I hope this is helpful.

Good luck!

Comment: Changing `dbinom(z, n.flips, p)` to `dbinom(0:n.flips, n.flips, p)` causes "Tie" to become non-zero (improvement!). I'm curious if the following is also a problem point: `y <- sapply(0:n.flips, function(k) ...`? The line just above this one that computes `y1` calls `sapply(0:m, function(k) ...` - should that not be the same? If I make _this_ change, "Win" now becomes non-zero.